# biblatex: citepages suppress adds space

Tags: biblatex, formatting

In a book project, I have a specific format definition for journal articles: title volume (year), issue, page (if exists as option to the `cite` command).

I want to omit the page range from journal article citations in the text, but not in the bibliography. That's what the `biblatex` option `citepages=suppress` is for, I thought. But somehow biblatex inserts an unnecessary space after the issue number. The bibliography is correct! Also if I use `citepages=separate` the citation format is correct, but of course with the page range I do not want. See MWE.

I tried tweaking the format definition but this is a bit beyond my biblatex finetunig skills. I would be grateful for a hint how to adapt my MWE.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=22.2cm,paperwidth=14cm,bottom=2.11cm,top=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,textwidth=10.8cm,textheight=18.49cm,includeheadfoot,headsep=5mm]{geometry}%footskip=1.51cm
\setlength{\parindent}{3.5mm}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[nobottomtitles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[force]{filehook}%muss vor standalone stehen
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand{\abk}{\textscale{0.9}}%Definition für Akronyme nur 90% groß
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Article{Article2009,
  author     = {Author, An},
  title      = {Articletitle},
  journal    = {Journal},
  pages      = {1-14},
  volume     = {3},
  year       = {2009},
  number     = {5},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-inote,sorting=nyt,bibencoding=utf8,citereset=chapter,citepages=suppress,refsection=none,autocite=footnote,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false,date=short]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
%\addbibresource{testbib.bib}    

  %Zeitschriftenformat: Titel Vol. (date), Nr., Seiten
  \renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{9pt}{11}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
Text.\footcite[4]{Article2009} 

\appendix
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a case of a forgotten `%` in the redefinition of `journal+issuetitle`, specifically in the line with `\printfield{eid}`.

Things look as expected with the following definition

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=verbose-inote, sorting=nyt,
  citepages=suppress,
  isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,eprint=false,
  date=short]{biblatex}

%Zeitschriftenformat: Titel Vol. (date), Nr., Seiten
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}%
  \newunit}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Article2009,
  author     = {Author, An},
  title      = {Articletitle},
  journal    = {Journal},
  pages      = {1-14},
  volume     = {3},
  year       = {2009},
  number     = {5},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text.\footcite[4]{Article2009} 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: An Author. “Articletitle”. In: Journal 3 (2009), 5, p. 4.]

Comment: It is just incredible. These little things messing everything up. Thank you!